# Add loader on button click in react/redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, loader, higher-order-components

I'm trying to add a Loader as Higher-Order-Component on button click in react/redux application.

Already have working Loader component and styling, just need to set logic when button is clicked show loader and hide existing button.

**Button component**:

```
import React from 'react'

import '../../../styles/components/_statement-print.scss';
import Loader from './Loader';

const StatementPrint = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>

      <button
        className="print-statement-button"
        onClick={props.handleStatementPrint}>PRINT
      </button>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader(StatementPrint);
```

**Loader**:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

import '../../../styles/components/_loader.scss';

const Loader = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class Loader extends Component {
    render() {
      return this.props.handleStatementPrint // Where must be logic when to show loader or existing button component
        ? <button className="loader-button">
            <div className="loader">
              <span className="loader-text">LOADING...</span>
            </div>
          </button>
        : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

In Loader component i added comment where need to write logic when to set loader or button.

I followed this example: [ReactCasts - Higher Order Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTunyI2Oyzw&t=510s)

I searched a lot of examples but most of them shows how to set loader then is data is fetching, but in my case i just need to show then onClick method is triggered.

So how to set logic when onClick method is fired? Is this is a good aproach? Also it will be better to try acomplish this doing with redux state, but don't know how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make small modifications to achieve what you want.
The wrapper component `Loader` can have a `isLoading` state, on the basis of which you can decide whether to show the loader span or the wrapped component.

This state `isLoading` can be updated by the wrapped component by passing `showLoader` function as a prop.

**Button component**

```
import React from 'react'

import '../../../styles/components/_statement-print.scss';
import Loader from './Loader';

const StatementPrint = ({handleStatementPrint, showLoader}) => {
  return (
    <div>

      <button
        className="print-statement-button"
        onClick={() => {
          showLoader();
          handleStatementPrint();
        }}>
        PRINT
      </button>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader(StatementPrint);
```

**Loader**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

import '../../../styles/components/_loader.scss';

const Loader = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class Loader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoading: false
      }

      this.showLoader = this.showLoader.bind(this);
    }

   showLoader() {
     this.setState({isLoading: true});
   }

    render() {
      return this.state.isLoading 
        ? <button className="loader-button">
            <div className="loader">
              <span className="loader-text">LOADING...</span>
            </div>
          </button>
        : <WrappedComponent 
            {...this.props} 
            showLoader={this.showLoader}
          />
    }
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

**EDIT**

- Since `handleStatementPrint` was required to be called, I have updated the click handler to include that function.
- Also using de-structuring to avoid typing `props` repeatedly. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for more info.

Comment: This is good, but i cant to pass showLoader() function to onClick method via props because it already uses another function that is passed from container that contains WrappedComponent logic

Comment: What is the name of that function? Is it `handleStatementPrint`? Let me know I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes it is handleStatementPrint.

Comment: Now i'm getting TypeError: showLoader is not a function.

Comment: Are you using de-structuring like this - ({handleStatementPrint, showLoader}) in `StatementPrint`?

Comment: Nevermind it was my silly mistake i forgot curly braces doing de-structuring. Thanks for great response.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and accept the answer if you got what you wanted :)

Comment: No. You accepted someone else's answer. Please click accept on my answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed it.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just some external state is needed.
If you can't have external state (eg isLoading) than you could pass a function into a loader hoc which will derive isLoading from current props

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8n08qoo3j2

Comment: Here is a more complicated example of mine https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/36c94276cbfa6247f111fbc0fcc68f37

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful.